# error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

> ```
> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
>
> 46     <ng-container *ngFor="let userFormGroup of
> usersForm.get('users')['controls']; let i=index">
>                                           
>  46:48 - error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because 
>  type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to
>  call 'get'?
>
>   46     <ng-container *ngFor="let userFormGroup of
>   usersForm.get('users')['controls']; let i=index">
> ```

---

**TS File**

```typescript
public usersForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() :void {
    this.usersForm = this.fb.group({
      users: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          gHService: [''],
          quantity: [''],
          startTime: [''],
          endTime: [''],
          remarks: ['']         
        })
      ])
    })
  }

  removeFormControl(i: number) {
    let usersArray = this.usersForm.get('users') as FormArray;
    usersArray.removeAt(i);
  }

  addFormControl() {
    let usersArray = this.usersForm.get('users') as FormArray;
    let arraylen = usersArray.length;

    let newUsergroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
          gHService: [''],
          quantity: [''],
          startTime: [''],
          endTime: [''],
          remarks: [''] 
    })

    usersArray.insert(arraylen, newUsergroup);
  }
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.usersForm.value);
  }
```

**Template File**

```html
<form [formGroup]="usersForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let userFormGroup of usersForm.get('users')['controls']; let i=index">
      <div [formGroup]="userFormGroup">
        <label>
          Service Name:
          <input type="text" formControlName="gHService">
        </label>
        <label>
          Quantity:
          <input type="text" formControlName="quantity">
        </label>
        <label>
          Start Time:
          <input type="text" formControlName="startTime">
        </label>
        <label>
          End Time:
          <input type="text" formControlName="endTime">
        </label>
        <label>
          Remarks:
          <input type="text" formControlName="remarks">
        </label>
        <label>
          <button (click)="removeFormControl(i)">remove formGroup</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <button (click)="addFormControl()">add new user formGroup</button>
```

Comment: Form Is Working Perfectly Fine,
But That Error in The Console is Annoying Me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As the error states `'AbstractControl' has no index signature`. You need a way to inform `typescript` that `usersForm.get('users')` returns a `FormArray`

In your TS File

```typescript
get userFormGroups () {
  return this.usersForm.get('users') as FormArray
}
```

In your html

```html
<form [formGroup]="usersForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div formArrayName='users'>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let userFormGroup of userFormGroups.controls; let i=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">

          <!--Other codes here -->
```

Note the lines

```html
<div formArrayName='users'>
```

And

```html
<div [formGroupName]="i">
```

Comment: `error TS2740: Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.
    
    47       <div [formGroup]="userFormGroup">`

Comment: Still Getting This Error

Comment: I have added some code that should help with the new error

Comment: `error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'.

47             <div [formGroup]="i">`

Comment: Now This Error :/

Comment: Just made a minor change, `<div [formGroupName]="i">` instead of `<div [formGroup]="i">`

Comment: Now Working Fine Without Any Error,
Thankyou So Much.. :)

Comment: Great to be helpful

Comment: One More Question,
How To get `gHService` Control in TS File ?

Comment: You can access `gHService` by `this.userFormGroups.controls[i].get('gHService').value`. `i` here represents the ith group

Comment: i is the index, you can make i zero e.g `this.userFormGroups.controls[0].get('gHService').value`

Comment: `error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'number[]'.
console.log(this.userFormGroups.controls?[0].get('gHService').value);`

Still Getting This Error?

Comment: Try removing the question mark see if it works or change to `controls?.[0]` note the dot

Comment: After Removing The Question Mark, It Say Object is Possibly NULL,
And `controls?.[0]` & `controls.[0]` is not Working

Comment: Actually I'm Using That `gHService` in  a Dropdown & If It is Selected Then Other 4 Field Would be Enable, By Default All 4 Fields Are Disable So Just Need To Access The Controls Directly

Comment: Problem Solved 
`this.userFormGroups.controls[0].get('gHService')?.value`
Just Need To Add Question Mark After `('gHService')` :D

Comment: I missed that too :)