# Error when including FormArray in FormBuilder

Tags: angular, formbuilder, formarray, form-control, formgroups

I am creating reactive forms in Angular. In it, I am trying to `embedded FormArray` in my existing `FormBuilder`. Below are the code details.

**Logic in component file**

```
this.addLoadTypeForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      'loanDescription': new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(20)]),
        users: new FormArray([
        new FormControl('test'),
        new FormControl('Testing')
      ])
    })
```

**Code in HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="addLoadTypeForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        descriptions
                    </label>
                    <textarea formControlName='loanDescription'></textarea>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group" formArrayName="users">
                    <label>Users</label>
                    <div *ngFor="let control of addLoadTypeForm.controls.users['controls'];let i=index">
                        <!-- <input type="text" [formControlName]="i"> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Error which I am getting**

> Element implicity has an `any` type because type `AbstarctControl` has
> no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?

**PS: I also tried with "let control of addLoadTypeForm.get('control')['controls']; let i = index;" still didn't work for me**

[image]

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202199/error-ts7052-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-abstractcontrol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error TS7052: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202199/error-ts7052-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-because-type-abstractcontrol)

Comment: After following the steps mentioned in above link I am not getting error, but now I am not able to see the binded data on the screen.

Comment: May be this example will help you [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-matautocomplte-infinite-scroll-cefsps?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: to add a FormArray using formBuilder use this.formbuilder.array, to add a FormControl you **not** use new FormControl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470645/angular-only-set-required-if-button-is-clicked/68474549#68474549

Answer (score 0):

Form controls inside FormArray are unnamed you can use them with formControl instead of formControlName

```
<div *ngFor="let control of addLoadTypeForm.controls.users['controls'];let i=index">
     <input type="text" [formControl]="control">
</div>
```